# "Animators may only be run on Looper threads" during on-device intrumentation testing

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4, android-testing

This is my test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class WelcomeActivityTests extends BaseTest {

    ApplicationController applicationController;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<WelcomeActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(WelcomeActivity.class);

    ArgumentCaptor<Callback> argumentCaptor;

    @Before
    @Override public void setUp() {
        applicationController = (ApplicationController) InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        applicationController.setMockMode(true);
        argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Callback.class);
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException {

        onView(withId(R.id.btnLogInW)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.email)).perform(typeText("good.email@example.com"));
        onView(withId(R.id.passL)).perform(typeText("strong.password"));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnLogInL)).perform(click());

        User user = new User();
        user.first_name = "Fake name";
        user.last_name = "Fake name";
        user.id = 1;
        user.email = "fake.email@gmail.com";

        AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponse();
        authResponse.api_key = "fake_api_key";
        authResponse.status = "ok";
        authResponse.user = user;

        Mockito.verify(api).login(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), argumentCaptor.capture());
        argumentCaptor.getValue().success(authResponse, null);

        assert true;
    }

    @After
    public void release() {
        applicationController.setMockMode(false);
    }

}
```

Buttons I'm clicking using espresso are based on material theme and they probably have some animations underneath. The outcome is that when I try to run some intrumentation tests app crashes every time i perform a click. I tried turn off animation in system developers options but it didn't help.

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on
>   Looper threads at
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1002) at
>   android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1050) at
>   android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:829) at
>   android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:585) at
>   android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:187)
>   at
>   android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:180)
>   at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15988) at
>   android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:3659) at
>   android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:16032) at
>   android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:6724) at
>   android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1446) at
>   my.app.ui.fragments.welcome.LoginFragment.unlock(LoginFragment.java:263)
>   at
>   my.app.ui.fragments.welcome.LoginFragment$4.success(LoginFragment.java:224)
>   at
>   my.app.ui.fragments.welcome.LoginFragment$4.success(LoginFragment.java:222)
>   at
>   my.app.WelcomeActivityTests.testRate(WelcomeActivityTests.java:84)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>   at
>   android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
>   at
>   android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:257)
>   at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:228)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)

This is the line, that crashes my app:

```
btnFacebook.setEnabled(false);
```

Edit: I found proper solution, look for accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I found a proper solution! When dealing with libraries and apis that use **Handlers** you need to annotate your test cases with **@UiThreadTest**. Also, every asynchronouos callback you are stubbing should be invoked using **runOnMainSync(Runnable r)** method of Instrumentation. Example:

```
    @Test
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testLoginSuccess() {

        Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().addMonitor(EventsListActivity.class.getName(), null, true);

        onView(withId(R.id.btnLogInW)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.email)).perform(typeText("good.email@example.com"));
        onView(withId(R.id.passL)).perform(typeText("strong.password"));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnLogInL)).perform(click());

        User user = new User();
        user.first_name = "Fake name";
        user.last_name = "Fake name";
        user.id = 1;
        user.email = "fake.email@gmail.com";

        final AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponse();
        authResponse.api_key = "fake_api_key";
        authResponse.status = "ok";
        authResponse.user = user;

        Mockito.verify(api).login(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), argumentCaptor.capture());
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                argumentCaptor.getValue().success(authResponse, null);
            }
        });

        assertThat(1, equalTo(monitor.getHits()));
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(monitor);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the line in a simulated thread:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        btnFacebook.setEnabled(false);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It makes it work but it's not the solution. Testing app shouldn't have any impact on app's code. I'd need to wrap every invocation of setEnabled and similar functions triggering animations in Handlers, which is very boiler plate heavy workaround.

Comment: but your code works, really? If so, there shoudlnt be impact in your code! you have to apply the workaround in tests somehow!

Comment: What I meant is that my app works fine without Handler. What makes it crash is running Instrumentation Tests. The way AndroidJUnit4 test runner deals with my threads is the problem. I think that Retrofit uses Handler to pass Callback itself, but it somehow doesn't work in testing environment.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution so I am accepting your answer. If I find something else I will update my post. Thanks!

Comment: its not a solution for main problem of this question but it solve many thread related problem specially those controls that need delay to execute for sync with main thread. anyway, it may throw exception like "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" you can easily solve that exception by providing Looper.getMainLooper() reference with Handler instance like new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(...